# How to do row padding in grouped data using WITH FILL in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Can someone tell me about the WITH FILL function.
Specifically, in the example, if you apply the function to the table, then at the output I get a table with a filled in missing date with the data from the line above - the first screen.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY
            Table1.date  WITH FILL
                TO toDate(now())
                STEP INTERVAL 1 day
                INTERPOLATE (subject as subject, amount as amount)
```

[image]

But if the data in the columns differs, as in the second screen, but there are all the necessary dates, then such a query will return the original table back, which is logical - with fill is done by date. And i dont need it.
[image]

The query needs to return a table with missing values ​​by date for both the first subject and the second. is it possible to do so - 3 screen/ That what i need.
[image]